# Serializing ENUM Singleton

Tags: java, file, serialization, snakeyaml

I'm trying to serialize an ENUM singleton instance (as described by Joshua Bloch in his book Effective Java) to a file. The ENUM instance is a simple JavaBean as this:

```
public enum ElvisFan implements Serializable{
  INSTANCE;
  private int totalSongsListened;

private ElvisFan(){
     totalSongsListened=0;
}

public void set(int v){
     totalSongsListened=v;
}

public int get(){
     return totalSongsListened;
}

}
}
```

I'm successfully using this enum all over my program but when I write this enum to a file using snakeyaml, I just have `!!com.chown.ElvisFan 'INSTANCE'` in my `test.yaml` file. This is what I'm doing:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
yaml.dump(ElvisFan.INSTANCE, new FileWriter("test.yml");
```

I also tried this without any luck:

```
JavaBeanDumper dumper = new JavaBeanDumper();
dumper.dump(ElvisFan.INSTANCE, new FileWriter("test.yml");
```

Can someone please guide me on this. Thanks!

**[Edited]**

Code correction.

Comment: enums are not supposed to have state. And you have only one value in your enum. Seems like you're using the wrong tool for the job. Don't you just want a regular singleton (a class)? Can't you not use a singleton at all?

Comment: You are right. I agree that Enum should be stateless but I'm just giving it a try to see if I ever stumble upon this kind of enum, what could be the way to serialize the file. Please note that I'm not asking this in "is this a good design practice" fashion. I'm just asking "how can I do this?" It is not that hard to convert this class to a non-enum singleton class so overall it boils down to: if you ever get a class such as this, how would you write to a file?

Comment: SnakeYAML treats enums as scalars. (unless you you force it to use mapping node in JavaBeanDumper)
You have to provide a custom Representer to dump such unusual enum as a JavaBean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singletons don't reakky make any sense. Serialisable singletons make even less sense. There is by definition only one singleton. So when you deserialise a singleton you are not going to get a new object. You will get the same old instance with the same old data.

Enums serialisation is handled specially. They are represented by name and type. No other state is saved, because as previously stated that doesn't make any sense.

I suggest modifying your code to avoid mutable statics.

Enums should not have mutable state. Serialising enums with a single instance can make sense where they implement some other class, such as `Comparator`, or are use as a key or somesuch.

Comment: that's what i need to attain - same old data and the same old instance. I'm pretty much sure the data can be saved because snakeyaml documentation provides a similar example on dumping/loading enum data: http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Enum

Comment: Which old instance? The old instance that exists, or the old "instance" that doesn't really exist in serialised form.

Answer (score 0):

SnakeYAML treats a List as a sequence not as a mapping even though List has also getters (getFirst()).
Why do you expect enum to be serialized as map ?

You have to provide a custom Representer to dump such an unusual enum as a JavaBean.
Tests contain a lot of examples how to write a custom Representer/Constructor.